# Probability, one bag or two?

Tags: probability, approximation

**Scenario 1**
Say you have two bags, A and B. Bag A contains 1 white ball and 2 black ball. Bag B contains 2 white balls and 3 black balls. You have to chose one of the bags randomly and pick one ball out of the bag you chose.

What is the probability that you'll get a white ball?

P(W) = The probability that the ball you pick is white.

P(A) = The probability that you choose bag A
P(B) = The probability that you choose bag B
P(W|A) = The probability that you pick a white ball given that you choose bag A
P(W|B) = The probability thar you pick a white ball given that you choose bag B

$P(W) = [P(A)\times P(W|A)] + [P(B)\times P(W|B)]$
$P(W) = [\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{3}] + [\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2}{5}]$
$P(W) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{5}$
$P(W) = \frac{11}{30}$

**Scenario 2**
Bag B contains 2 white balls and 1 black ball.$P(W) = [P(A)\times P(W|A)] + [P(W)\times P(W|B)]$
$P(W) = [\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{3}] + [\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{2}{3}]$
$P(W) = \frac{3}{6}$

Notice that for **scenario 2** we can consider the two bags as *one* bag. The total number of balls is 3 (bag A) + 3 (bag B) = **6**. The total number of white balls = 1 (bag A) + 2 ( bag B) = **3**. $P(W) = \frac{3}{6}$

However this is *not true* for **scenario 1**. The total number of balls = 3 (bag A) + 5 (bag B) = **8**. The total number of white balls = 1 (bag A) + 2 (bag B) = **3**. And ... most importantly ... $P(W) \ne \frac{3}{8}$.

BUT ...

For **sceanrio 1** we see that $\frac{3}{8} - \frac{11}{30} = \frac{1}{120} \approx 0.008...$. 0.008... is a *really small* difference, which lends some *legitimacy* to treating the two bags as *one* bag.

**Why can we sometimes treat two bags as one bag (scenario 2) and at other times not (scenario 1)?**

Thank you.

**Addendum**

If P(W|A) = $\frac{a}{b}$ and P(W|B) = $\frac{c}{d}$ then ...

### when is $P(W) = [P(A)\times \frac{a}{b}] + [P(B)\times \frac{c}{d}] = \frac{a + c}{b + d}$??

**EDIT**

After all the helpful answers:

The problem boils down to:

Where $x$ and $y$ and $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ are *proper rational fractions*

$x(\frac{a}{b}) + y(\frac{c}{d}) = \frac{a + c}{b + d}$ ... equation (i)

AND

$x + y = 1$ ... equation (ii)

Comment: Take out the probability of choosing a bag, $\frac12$ as a common factor, and compare the two cases ....

Comment: [$\frac{a}{b}\times \frac{c}{d}] + [\frac{e}{f}\times \frac{g}{h}] = \frac{c + g}{d + h}$

Comment: I don't know what you are writing. Originally: Case $1: (1/2)(1/3+2/5)$ Case $2: (1/2)(1/3 + 2/3)$ For generalised case, you can't just add.

Comment: @trueblueanil, can you reread the question, please. I made some edits.

Comment: While the equations are true, they give no help in deciding whether you can merge or not without making the full computation, unless $x=y = \frac12$

Comment: @trueblueanil. If given $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$, I think I get a *partial solution* to the two *simultaneous equations*. To find $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ from $x$ and $y$ is more problematic. I could specify a condition that links $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ though to get the *other equation*. Correct?

Comment: If each bag is equally likely to be chosen, *by inspection* I can see if they can be combined, and reach a solution faster by combining . If I have to *check* through a full calculation whether I can combine or not, what is the benefit ??

Comment: You have a point. Do you see any *practical* value to the solution to my problem, over and above the one you mentioned (simply adding the numerators and the denominators). It's very similar to something that I learned a few sols ago, that $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{a + c}{b + d} < \frac{c}{d}$? Any connexion?

Comment: I think  full juice has been extracted from this problem ! $\;\;$ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally misinterpreted the question being asked, and my answer was somewhat misleading and implied incorrect things.  true blue anil’s answer is correct, but let me add a proof for this, as well as a generalization.

If $p_A$ and $p_B$ are the probabilities of picking a white ball from bag $A$ and $B$ respectively, (in other words, they are the proportions of white balls to total balls for each respective bag), and $\lambda$ is the fraction of the total balls that are in  bag A (so $(1-\lambda)$ is the fraction in bag B), and $\nu$ is the probability of choosing bag A (so $(1-\nu)$ is the probability of picking bag B), then the probability of picking a white ball when the bags are chosen first is $\nu p_A+(1-\nu)p_B$, whereas the probability of picking a white ball from the combined bag is $\lambda p_A + (1-\lambda)p_B$.  Therefore the two probabilities will coincide if and only if
\begin{align*}
\nu p_A+(1-\nu)p_B & = \lambda p_A + (1-\lambda)p_B\\
(\nu-\lambda)p_A + ((1-\nu)-(1-\lambda))p_B &= 0\\
(\nu-\lambda)p_A + (\lambda-\nu)p_B &=0\\
(\nu-\lambda)p_A - (\nu-\lambda)p_B &=0\\
(\nu-\lambda)(p_A-p_B) &=0\text{.}
\end{align*}
The last equation holds if and only if one of the two factors equals $0$, meaning either

1. $p_A=p_B$, i.e., the proportion of white balls in bag A is the same as the proportion in bag B.

or

2. $\lambda=\nu$, i.e., the probability of picking bag A is the same as the proportion of total balls in bag A.  In the special case under consideration ("scenario 2"), this is true with $\lambda=\nu=\frac{1}{2}$.

#### Remark

Intuitively, you can think of the explanation as being that combining the bags reweighs the probabilities so that the odds of picking each individual ball is the same, which would only have been true in the former case if $\lambda=\nu$.  So if $\lambda=\nu$, then you haven't changed the probability of picking any given ball.  If you HAVE changed the probabilities of picking individual balls, weighing the balls in one bag more heavily than before, then you need the proportion of whites in each bag to be the same (i.e., $p_A=p_B$) in order for this re-weighing not to matter.

#### Addendum

Regarding the edit to the original post, which asks for simultaneous solutions to

$$x(\frac{a}{b}) + y(\frac{c}{d}) = \frac{a + c}{b + d}\tag{i}$$
(I have edited (i) from the original post to correct for the intended meaning)

and
$$ x+y=1\text{,} \tag{ii}$$

in the above analysis $x=\nu$, $y=1-\nu$, $\frac{a}{b}=p_A$, $\frac{c}{d}=p_B$, $\frac{b}{b+d}=\lambda$, and $\frac{d}{b+d}=(1-\lambda)$.
Therefore, if (ii) is satisfied, then (i) becomes equivalent to the condition that either

1. $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$,

or

2. $x = \frac{b}{b+d}$ (or equivalently, $y=\frac{d}{b+d}$).

Comment: Indeed, it boils down to the *equiprobability* of picking one ball. You can treat two bags as one if (by your solution), 1) the bags contain the same number of balls, 2) the probability of choosing a one bag = the probability of choosing the other bag. Muchas gracias, mon ami.

Comment: It is incorrect to say that both bags must have the same number of balls.

Comment: @trueblueanil thanks for the correction

Comment: @MW, can you take a look at my edited question?

Comment: @AgentSmith done, I addressed the edit.  I think that's probably going to be it for me on this one unless someone finds another mistake.

Answer (score 3):

(You ask "Why can we sometimes treat two bags as one bag (scenario 2) and at other times not (scenario 1)?"

I assume that the bags have equiprobability of being chosen, as is usual for such problems.

Then suppose bag A has $a$ white balls, $b$ black ones, while bag B has $c$ white balls and $d$ black ones,

for us to be able to combine the bags into one,

$P(white) = \frac12\frac{a}{a+b} + \frac12\frac{c}{c+d} \;\;must= \frac{a+c}{a+b+c+d}$

This can only occur if  $\frac{a}{a+b}= \frac{c}{c+d}$

ie the probability of drawing white from each bag is equal, **OR** the total number of balls in each bag is equal.

Yout Scenario $2$ works because of the second clause, ie equal number of balls in both bags.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by what you mean here when you say the two probabilities (of drawing white from either bag) are complementary.  Certainly if there are more balls total in bag B, then complementary probabilities should not allow combining the bags, example, there's 4 white and 1 black in bag A, 8 blacks and 2 whites in bag B.  then actual prob of white is $\frac{4}{2\cdot 5}+\frac{2}{2\cdot 10} = \frac{1}{2}$, but combining bags gives prob of $\frac{6}{15}=\frac{2}{5}$, right?

Comment: @MW: Oh, I also botched up, forgot to add that in this particular case the total number of balls in both boxes must be identical. Amended.

Comment: But once the bags are equal size the complementary probability condition is unnecessary, it just works regardless.  I think the right statement is the bags must be equal size, OR the proportions in the individual bags must be equal, but haven’t sat down to check yet.

Comment: @MW: But the equiprobability of choosing each bag has to be there. Actually you have caught me at a very wrong time, (watching US Open !), Simplifying, tx.